# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at build.js:1 vuejs, webpack, SSR (i used npm script-loader but no use)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuex, vuetify.js

getting error while integrating bundle.js, and i used "script-loader" in but no use.
libraries used
vuejs, vuex, ssr, vuetify, webpack.js

Error:

```
  build.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
  at build.js:1 .
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

change script from

```
  <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
```

to

```
  <script nomodule src="/dist/build.js"></script>
```

add nomodule attribute in script tag, its happen because we used  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'  in webpack config

finally my index.html will be like

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>

  </head>
 <body>


   <script nomodule src="/dist/build.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Note:

```
do not make any changes in src attribute
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work. No errors in console, but code also doesn't load